# Google API access token returning 400 - "invalid_request"

Tags: google-oauth

I'm making the following request to google oauth2 to get the access token and am getting the 400 http response with "invalid_request":

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NING/1.0
Content-Length: 260
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

With the following parameters in the request body:

```
Map(redirect_uri -> http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Foauth%2Fgsheet, client_id -> _.apps.googleusercontent.com, code -> 4/9hzannwi_UlYWFlFEivgYXKzdGs6._, client_secret -> _, grant_type -> authorization_code)
```

This is really bugging me, any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was encoding the redirect_uri prior to making the request which was causing an issue. Not doing this solved the problem. This seems odd however as I encode the redirect_uri when sending the user to the oauth2 request page...